# Is there any library or short way in Javascript for map nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array like this.

```
let Array = [{
  id: 1,
  name: "Car",
  cars: [{
    id: 2,
    name: "Hyundai",
    models: [
      "Verna", "Aura", "Azera", "Accent", "Sonata"
    ]
  }]
}....]
```

And I think this not the best way: `Array.map(car => car.cars.map(model => model.models))`.
Is there any other way?

Comment: Do not use the name `Array` for a variable. It the name of a default object in JS. -- Also you could use `flatMap` to get a single array of values

Comment: what is your expected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 'short way' as what you are doing is very specific to your problem. The way you wrote it is the most concise if you want to end up with an array like:

```
let Array = [
  [
    [ "Verna", "Aura", "Azera", "Accent", "Sonata" ],
    [ ... ],
  ],
  [ ... ],
]
```

But if you want to flatten the array, you can consider writing it as:

```
Array
  .map(car => car.cars).flat()
  .map(model => model.models).flat()
```

This will result in an array like this:

```
[ "Verna", "Aura", "Azera", "Accent", "Sonata", ... ]
```

##### Notes

Do not call an array `Array` as is the name of the array constructor. You will lose the ability to do `new Array()`.